# WCF MaxReceivedMessageSize: maximum message size quota exceeded

Tags: wcf

I am getting this error:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

How can I increase this value in the WCF client application or the server application, and if possible an example of how this is done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You increase it on the client side in app/web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSBigQuotaConfig" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2097152" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2097152" maxArrayLength="2097152" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <client>
      <endpoint 
          address="http://example.com/endpoint.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WSBigQuotaConfig"
          contract="ISomeServiceContract" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: +1 and Accepted, but also worth mentioning that when transfer mode = buffered - maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize should contain the same value....

Comment: A mismatch between maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize gives exception.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the MaxReceivedMessageSize attribute in your binding configuration. By default, it is 65536. I assume you're using data sets or something of that nature that end up being pretty large (mostly because they're represented with XML usually).

The good news is that I think you only need to change this in your client configuration. Take a look below.

```
<bindings>
   <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="MyTcpBinding"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000"/>
   </netTcpBinding>
<bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding_Username" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"          maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_Username"
            contract="Exchange.Exweb.ExchangeServices.ExchangeServicesGenericProxy.ExchangeServicesType"
            name="ServicesFacadeEndpoint" />
</client>
```