# WCF HTTP EndPoint Volume

Tags: wcf

WCF service feeds SilverLight Production App or Windows Test application (VS2010)
They ask for collection of Datapoints.
Small collection no problem. You can debug end to end and all is good.
'Big' collection (10000 items approx maybe 120kB data) trouble.

For SilverLight the FireFox Firebug shows a HttP abort.
The Silver Async EndInvoke appears to kick off then wanders into the weeds without any error indication.

For the Windows App 
The client base.Channel.GetReadings shows a CommunicationException which says see server logs for more details. I can't find anything in EventViewer that seems relevant.

Any ideas on how to proceed from here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the [MaxReceivedMessageSize on your client and service config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573606/wcf-maxreceivedmessagesize-question) to a values greater that 120KB? WCF defaults to 64K maximum message size (rant: which probably has caused untold millions of dollars of lost productivity all in the name of "security"). If you have already set this attribute correctly, then [try this link to set up WCF tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx) to capture what WCF is actually doing.